# How to replace a #define with a stringstream type method

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to replace a `#define` function like the following:

```
#define DEBUG(x) do { std::cout << x << std::endl; } while(0)
```

with a more RAII type error tracking object. This tracking object currently resembles this (**updated to include "intro" for clarity; and included stack dump logic from Ahmed AEK*):

```
class tracker() {
public:
  tracker(std::string s) : intro(s) {}
  ~tracker() {
    if( this->stack.empty()) return;
    // dump_the_stack
    std::cout << "Messages from: " << intro << std::endl;
    for (const auto& item: stack) {
        std::cout << " * " << item;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // throw (abort)
  }
  void add( const std::string& message ) {
    stack.push_back( message );
  }
private:
  std::string intro;
  std::vector<const std::string> stack;
};
```

I would like to use this while keeping the existing `#define` syntax. For instance, I would like to have a method that allows the class user to maintain a syntax resembling one of these:

```
tracker.add( "value exceeded: " << value );
```

or even:

```
tracker << "value exceeded: " << value << std::endl;
```

Ideally, I believe the solution I want would look like:

```
tracker::add( ostringstream os ) {
  stack.push_back( os.str() + std::endl );
}
```

But it appears that there's no implicit conversion to ostringstream for the first case, and there's no way to determine the terminal `<<` in an `operator<<()` case. Is there a simple solution here that I'm overlooking?

---

**EDIT: for clarification below, and added "intro" to sample class above:**

My ideal scenario is being able to use the syntax in either of these two test cases:

Case 1 (preferred):

```
int main()
{
    tracker t("test case 1");
    int trace = 0;

    t.add("hello world 1!" << " trace: " << ++trace);
    t.add("hello world 2!" << " trace: " << ++trace);
    return 0;
}
```

Case 2 (acceptable):

```
int main()
{
    tracker t("test case 1");
    int trace = 0;

    t << "hello world 1!" << " trace: " << ++trace;
    t << "hello world 2!" << " trace: " << ++trace;
    return 0;
}
```

The resultant output should look like:

```
    Messages from: test case 1
     * hello world 1! trace: 1
     * hello world 2! trace: 2
```

Comment: `tracker << "value exceeded: " << value << std::endl;` is possible if you make your class an `ostream` or give it a `<<` operator that creates an `ostream` and uses it. All the `<<` operators for ints, strings, etc are defined to work on `ostream&`.

Comment: Thanks @user253751, I think you're right. That is the simpler answer: using a class member operator<<. I'll post the solution once I have it cleaned up (if nobody else posts an acceptable answer first).

Comment: would `t.line() << "hello";` be ok ? If so then you just need a function called `line` that returns the class i wrote in my answer which you initialize with a reference to `t`, and if you want the `.add(` this needs to be a macro, but if you do use a macro you might as well make the macro insert a `std::endline` at the end.

Comment: converting `t.line() << "hello";` to `t << "hello";` would require you to overload the `operator<<` for input `T` to return the `.line()` object, so you end up with your syntax.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks for the suggestions. If I'm following, making a macro-like version of .add() _would_ solve my "endl" complaint but I want to move in the direction of removing cpp macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. Here is what I have ended up with. Though I would prefer to use the function-like interface to be more consistent with existing code, this does work well and addresses my immediate needs. The biggest nuisance is requiring an end-token for terminating the message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class tracker {
public:
  tracker(std::string s) : intro(s) {};
  ~tracker() {
    std::cout << "Messages from: " << intro << std::endl;
    for (const auto& item: stack) {
        std::cout << " * " << item << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  void add(std::string message ) {
    stack.push_back(std::move(message));
  }
  void operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)) { // catch std::endl
    this->add(linebuf.str());
    linebuf.str(std::string());
  }
  template <typename T>
  tracker& operator<<(T&& item) {
    linebuf << std::forward<T>(item);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::string intro;
  std::ostringstream linebuf;
  std::vector<std::string> stack;
};

int main()
{
    tracker t("test1");
    int trace = 0;

    t << "hello world 1!" << " trace: " << ++trace << std::endl;
    t << "hello world 2!" << " trace: " << ++trace << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [live example](https://www.online-cpp.com/6YvVwDLJxB), maybe...

Answer (score 2):

you can just print the output in the destructor of a temporary as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class tracker {
public:
  tracker() = default;
  ~tracker() {
    for (const auto& item: stack)
    {
        std::cout << item;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  void add(std::string message ) {
    stack.push_back(std::move(message));
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::string> stack;
};

tracker&&  operator<<(tracker&& tr, std::string item)
{
    tr.add(std::move(item));
    return std::move(tr);
}

#define DEBUG(X) tracker{} << X

int main()
{
    DEBUG("hello" << " " << "world!");
}
```

an unfortunate side-effect is the need to do `return std::move(tr);` and since the lifetime of this object extends up to the closing semi-colon, there is no UB or leaks here.

to be able to use any user-defined ostream overload you can create a free function that uses a stringstream as follows.

```
template <typename T>
tracker&& operator<<(tracker&& tr, T&& item)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T,std::string>)
    {
        tr.add(std::forward<T>(item));
    }
    else
    {
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << std::forward<T>(item);
        tr.add(s.str());
    }
    return std::move(tr);
}
```

Comment: `return tr;` should work in C++23 as well.

Comment: And I guess `tracker` should be non-copyable and non-movable.

Comment: Note that in this approach, the tracker's `vector` becomes useless since `tracker::add()` can never be called more than 1 time per `DEBUG()` call. Also, in the templated `operator<<`, consider moving the `stringstream` into an `else` of the `if constexpr` so you only need 1 `return`, and also use `ostringstream` instead of `stringstream`

Comment: @user17732522 - In my actual code I've set to 'delete' the copy, move, and operator= constructors. To Ahmed AEK: I wasn't aware that local objects persisted for the lifetime of the statement. But I'm having an issue with implementing operator<< because a different operator<< somehow gets undefined when I use this. I will look at this more closely with fresh eyes tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @rand'Chris `T&&` sinks all types, unless you constrict it with `std::enable_if` or concepts, you can make a concept that it requires `opreator<<` on ostream, to filter out things that don't.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for those hints. The proposed solution doesn't work the way I'd like for the reasons you mention; I updated the description to clarify my scenario. Regarding std::enable_if - my other operator<< overload that gets hidden is a template<T> and I _think_ I now have that restricted to std::vector<T,A>, but I still have issues there. I have an operator<< for a custom enum class that I can't make "too visible", but when I put the two overloads together in the same header in a test case they work fine. Separate issue...